# Does the primitive difference formula for a line integral work if the function is not analytic, but only differentiable, in the curve?

Tags: complex-analysis, curves, analyticity, line-integrals

So I'm following a book on complex analysis, and recently got to a theorem that states the following:

If $C$ is a smooth curve, $f$ is a function defined on $C$, and there exists some function $F$, analytic on $C$ such that $F' = f$, then $\int_C f = F(b) - F(a)$ where $a$ and $b$ are, respectively, the beginning and endpoints of the curve.

My question is: would this still be true if, instead of considering $F$ analytic, we consider it just differentiable in $C$? I don't see any reason why the proof would fail.

Comment: Does "analytic on a curve" make sense? (It's been a while since I did complex analysis). The way I've seen this stated is that if $C$ is a curve contained in the region $D$, and $F$ is analytic on $D$ with $F' = f$, then the integral $\int_C f = F(b) - F(a)$. There is a core theorem of complex analysis saying that a function being differentiable on an open set is equivalent to it being analytic on an open set.

Comment: I believe it is supposed to mean "analytic on all points of the curve". This is the wording the book uses, I believe (I'll check when I get the time).
But even then, the question remains: why does F have to be analytic on D, and not just differentiable on all points of the curve? Why is this insufficient? If it is, of course.

Comment: Well, if "analytic on all points of the curve" does indeed mean that there is an open set containing the curve, where $F$ is analytic, then you could equally well assume $F$ is differentiable on that open set, since these things are equivalent for functions on $\mathbb{C}$.